# Filter nested objects javascript

Tags: javascript, object, filter, nested

I can't get to solve this exercise

The called function receives as an argument an object 'guests', in the object we have objects that represent the guests at a party where they all have an "age" property.
You must return the number of guests who are under 18

In the following example it should return 2

I tried to solve it in several ways, at the moment it goes like this:

```
function howManyMinors(guest) {
    let guests = {
    Luna: {age: 25},
    Sebastian: {age: 7},
    Mark: {age: 34},
    Nick: {age: 15}
    };
      
    var minors = 0;
    for(element in guests) {
        if(Object.values(guests) <= 18) {
            minors ++;
        }
    }
    return minors;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `guests` when you mean `guests[element]`. And don't use `Object.values` when you just need `.age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the incoming parameter. There is no need to define an internal object inside of the function.

To compute the number of guests who are under 18, I would do something like:

```js
function howManyMinors(guests) {
let minors = 0;
  for (const guest of Object.values(guests)) {
    if (guest.age < 18) minors++;
  }
  return minors;
}

howManyMinors({
    Luna: {age: 25},
    Sebastian: {age: 7},
    Mark: {age: 34},
    Nick: {age: 15}
}); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much

I had been trying to solve it for a long time and you did it in a simple and fast way

I had already tried something similar but had problems accessing the value of the object. Now everything is clear to me

Answer (score 0):

The code you attached is not clear. For example, you don't use the `guest` argument at all. If I understand you right, you have an object that each property of it represents a guest. Each guest is an object with an `age` property and your job is to count the guests with `age <= 18`.

If I understood you correctly, you can do something like this:

```js
const guests = {Luna: {age: 25},
    Sebastian: {age: 7},
    Mark: {age: 34},
    Nick: {age: 15}};

const count = Object.values(guests).reduce((count, value) => value.age <= 18 ? count + 1 : count, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, there is a better tool for the job which is [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function howManyMinors(guests) {
  return Object.values(guests).filter(guest => guest.age < 18).length;
}
const guests ={ Luna: { age: 25 }, Sebastian: { age: 7 }, Mark: { age: 34 }, Nick: { age: 15 } }
console.log(howManyMinors(guests)) // 2
```